# Информатика 23 ЕГЭ

Tags: python, рекурсия, информатика

[image: задание]Пытаюсь решать данное задание рекурсией, функция `g(n)`, возвращающая большее простое число работает, но когда вставляю ее во вторую функцию выдает ошибку, причем если заменить `g(x)` во второй функции на любое другое условие(число), например `x * 3`, то все работает. Помогите понять что не так и исправить по возможности, спасибо, вот код:

```
def g(n):       
    c = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            c += 1
    if c == 2:
        return n
    else:
        return g(n + 1)


def f(x, y):
    if x == y:
        return 1
    if x > y or x == 33:
        return 0
    if x < y:
        return f(x + 2, y) + f(g(x), y)


print(f(2, 14) * f(14, 45))
```

Comment: "выдает ошибку" - секретную?

Comment: ну да, мне вам надо было прикрепить ее или что? вот:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename", line 21, in <module>
    print(f(2, 14) * f(14, 45))
  File  "filename", line 18, in f
    return f(x + 2, y) + f(g(x), y)
  File  "filename", line 18, in f
    return f(x + 2, y) + f(g(x), y)
  File  "filename", line 18, in f
    return f(x + 2, y) + f(g(x), y)
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
  File  "filename", line 13, in f
    if x == y:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: Ну не сходятся ваши вычисления, функции вызываются по кругу и глубина рекурсии получается превышена

Comment: Вот это что делает? - f(x + 2, y) **+** f(g(x), y)

Comment: считает кол-во программ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**большее** *простое число*

```
f(g(x + 1), y)
      ^^^
```

Comment: да, выдает верный ответ, спасибо большое, а почему надо писать x+1, а не x? не совсем понимаю.

Comment: @Максим Напишите на листке бумаги что происходит, когда Вы заходите в функцию`f` с первым параметром равным простому числу.

Comment: дошло, спасибо еще раз!

Comment: @Максим Пожалуйста. Успехов.